# Making HTML show up as a link

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display messages from one user to another on the site. Messages are saved in a database with the HTML.

Why is the HTML on the site, showing up, instead of turning the HTML into a link or a line break?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h4><u>Your Messages</u></h4>
    @foreach (var m in Model.User.MessagesUsers)
    {
        <p>@m.Message</p>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: It's escaping all html tags for safety reasons. What framework are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: This is not pure HTML and CSS.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio

Comment: line breaks or links are showing up with the html instead of showing up as an actual link or line break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using ASP.NET MVC.  The framework automatically HTML-encodes the output for security reasons.

You can get around that by [using `@Html.Raw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740.aspx):

```
<p>@Html.Raw(m.Message)</p>
```

**Be aware** however that this is **circumventing security**.  Make sure you trust your data.  This is how cross-site scripting attacks happen.  You might also want to look into something like [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) to allow users to enter markup over which you have more control.

Comment: So is there no way around this without opening myself to a security risk?

Comment: @N.Sch: That depends on a number of factors.  If you're allowing users to enter data which you will display to them or other users without HTML-encoding it, then that's a security risk to those other users.  (Even HTML-encoding it may still present a risk.  I don't know of one, but that doesn't mean there isn't one.)  If you trust the source of the data, there's less of a risk.  But keep in mind that "trust" doesn't necessarily mean "a logged-in user posted it."  Logged-in users can do malicious things.

Comment: The safest approach is not to allow users to enter HTML, allow markdown (or something like it) and convert it to HTML on the fly, then it's safe (against XSS)